# should i put .hpp and .cpp in the same fold or in ./src and ./hdr respectively?

Tags: c++, netbeans

it seems that separate them into src and hdr is a popular solution. however, this is not the case in Netbeans: by default, netbeans will put both hpp and cpp files in the same directory.

questions:

1. should I separate them or not? why?
2. if 1 is yes, is there any way to automatically set this in Netbeans?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you plan to distribute a library as binaries and headers, it might be easier to have the headers in a separate directory to begin with.

Answer (score 4):

Headers for private module stuff, should be with your code, public headers for the module should be separate.

Answer (score 2):

This is a style preference, which means you should choose a style and stick with it.  Different shops have different styles and best behavior is to adapt to their style when working on their projects.

For C++, I prefer to have the headers in the same directory as the source files.  Many shops prefer to separate the header and source files into separate directories.